# Error: Could not start Service[puppetserver]: Execution of '/usr/bin/systemctl start puppetserver' returned 5:

Tags: ruby, puppet

I have installed the latest version puppet-server.

```
yum install -y puppet-server
```

Now I want to run the puppetmaster, but failed:

```
[root@puppet-master ~]# puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running


Error: Could not start Service[puppetserver]: Execution of '/usr/bin/systemctl start puppetserver' returned 5: Failed to start puppetserver.service: Unit not found.
Error: /Service[puppetserver]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[puppetserver]: Execution of '/usr/bin/systemctl start puppetserver' returned 5: Failed to start puppetserver.service: Unit not found.
service { 'puppetserver':
  ensure => 'stopped',
}
```

the version is:

```
[root@puppet-master ~]# puppet --version
3.8.7
```

Comment: Puppet 3.8.7 is obsolete and unsupported, and it does not interoperate with puppetserver.  You should remove it and install the puppet-agent package instead (it also provides a `puppet` command).  However, I am inclined to guess that that will not resolve the particular problem you describe.

Comment: The "unit not found" error smells like a packaging issue to me, but it's hard to be sure.  Get the correct packages in place, and if the problem persists then look into which Puppet packages you are using, from which repository.